# How to display relationships between different nodes

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, graphviz, pygraphviz

I would like to be able to see relationships between two nodes (or more).

Let's say I have those two paths:
1-2-4-5-7-8
1-3-4-6-7-8

From this we can see that nodes 2&5 are "linked together" and so are 3&6.

But if i just add those paths to a graph I end up with something like that:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

nx.add_path(G, [1,2,4,5,7,8])
nx.add_path(G, [1,3,4,6,7,8])

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Yet it doesn't show the relations between 2&5 and between 3&6 and it seems like I can have the combination 2&6 and 3&5 even though they don't exist in my initial paths.

Is there anyway to show this ?

I am coding this python and using the libraries networkx to build the graph and pygraphviz for the visualization/rendering.

Comment: Neither of your paths includes an arc from 2 to 5 nor from 3 to 6; both those traversals step across intermediate nodes.  What do you expect the drawing to show ?  And if you expect to see an arc from 2 to 5, why not from 1 to 4, and all the others ?

Comment: Maybe OP is meaning that the 2 chains are identical but one chain uses "2" and "5" whilst the other chain uses "3" and "5" on the same place. But OP should make it a bit more clear. Also OP should add the generated dot file. Maybe  a representation like: `digraph G {
  1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 7 -> 8;
  1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8
}` is more what is expected.

Comment: I understand the logic behind what is shown but what I mean is that, based on data I have, if I go on the path 1->2 then the following is always 2->4->5->7->8. And I never encounter such a path that would be 1->2->4->6->7->8. Basically 2->4->5 and 3->4->6 should be separated portions of the tree.

Comment: But that, iiuc, isn't possible. Each node name must be unique. So if 1has an edge to 2, and 2 to 4, then 1 and 4 are connected through node 2. So you'd probably have to rename nodes in different branches @florian

Comment: @yatu I suppose the only solution is to rename a node as the fusion of two nodes so that the path looks like (1,2)->(2,4)->(4,5)->(5,7)->(7,8). this way node (2->4) can never lead to node (4,6). It's not ideal but I guess I can work with that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Yet it doesn't show the relations between 2&5 and between 3&6

I think you may be confusing what a [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) actually is. By adding a path to your network, you're adding all contiguous nodes in the path as  edges. So adding the path `(1,2,4)` is the same ass adding the edges `((1,2), (2,4))`. Hence nodes `2` and `5` in your graph, are connected through the node sequence `2,4,5`, following this logic.

But with what you're describing, you'd need the combinations of all these nodes, something like:

```
from itertools import combinations

G = nx.DiGraph()

l1 = [1,2,4,5,7,8]
G.add_edges_from(combinations(l1, r=2))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

> and it seems like I can have the combination 2&6 and 3&5 even though they don't exist in my initial paths.

Nodes `2` and `6`, even though they are added through different paths, they are [connected](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedGraph.html), meaning that node `6` is accessible from node `2` through 1,**2,4**,5,7,8 and 1,3,**4,6**,7,8 from the second path.

Comment: I understand that node 6 is connected to nodes 2 and 3 through node 4 and that's exactly what I don't want. Based on data I have, I would like to represent the fact that node 5 can only appear if I come from node 2 and 4 and node 6 can only appear if I come from node 3 and 4. Basically the path 2->4->5 and 3->4->6 should be parallel branches of the tree.

Comment: I upvoted (I think ?) your last comment on my initial post but that particular answer did not help no. Here it shows edges that does not exist (1->8 or 1->5 for example).